# Why does cache work better in overlay2 than aufs?

Tags: docker, overlayfs, aufs

A follow-up from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510931/overlay-storage-driver-internals).

After reading Docker Storage drivers from [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#overlayfs-and-docker-performance) I understood that `overlay` was faster than `aufs` because it had only one hard linked image layer.

But for `overlay2`, document says `overlay2` supports multiple layers as `aufs`, but mitigates any performance hit with caching. I couldn't find any reference that was showing how `overlay2` is better at caching than `aufs`, can someone give me advices?